# Apply a `configMap` to EKS cluster with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am trying to apply a `configMap` to an EKS cluster through Terraform, but I don't see how. There is lots of documentation about this, but I don't see anyone succeeding with it, so I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Currently we control our infrastructure through Terraform. When I create the `.kube/config` file through AWS cli, and try to connect to the cluster, I get the `Unauthorized` error, which is documented how to solve [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error/); in AWS. According to the docs, we need to edit `aws-auth` configMap and add some lines to it, which configures API server to accept requests from a VM with certain role. The problem is that only cluster creator has access to connect to the cluster and make these changes. The cluster creator in this case is Terraform, so what we do is `aws config`, we add the credentials of Terraform to the VM from where we are trying to connect to the cluster, we successfully authenticate against it, add the necessary lines to the configMap, then revoke the credentials from the VM.

From there on, any user can connect to the cluster from that VM, which is our goal. Now we would like to be able to edit the configMap through Terraform object, instead of doing all this process. There is a resource `kubernetes_config_map` in Terraform, but that's a different provider (kubernetes), not AWS, so it is not being able to find the cluster, and fails with trying to connect to the API server running in localhost.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a resource kubernetes_config_map in Terraform, but that's a different provider (kubernetes), not AWS

It is a different provider, because Terraform should now interact with a different API (Kubernetes API instead of AWS API).

There are data sources for `aws_eks_cluster` and `aws_eks_cluster_auth` that can be used to authenticate the [kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs).

The [aws_eks_cluster_auth](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/eks_cluster_auth) has examples for authenticating the kubernetes provider:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.example.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.example.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.example.token
  load_config_file       = false
}
```

Another example is how the Cloud Posse AWS EKS module [authenticate the kubernetes provider](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-cluster/blob/master/auth.tf#L88-L131) and also use a `ConfigMap`.